# CSS3 flexbox: flexboxes inside flexboxes aren't contained inside their parents

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am faced with getting a rather complex web app to work in HTML/CSS. I am finding many issues with the flexbox, which seems like it would solve my problems. I'm trying to understand what I'm doing wrong or what the flexbox limitations are. I am only working in Chrome so that helps.

I keep seeing two issues:
- the boxes don't understand how to accommodate heights/widths of children contained inside
- child boxes aren't contained by parents. Image of this issue:

[image: screenshot of problem]

Instead of posting code here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dex3703/ryCQq/ 
Isn't fully complete but you get the idea I hope. The CSS is combined from three different files.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to show some code. Try to narrow it down as much as possible to the problem, or give a link to the webapp.

Comment: made a JSFiddle. Let me know if you can't get to it (brand new user...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out. All containers must be set to display: box (or -webkit-box, etc). If you want a box inside a box, they all must be boxes. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Seems like `display: box` is deprecated.